# ML predicting output based on single feature

Tags: machine-learning

I am a beginner in ML, I came across the below scenario. I wonder if I could use ML (and which kind) and what would be the the steps needed for the pre-processing of a time-series. So first (1)how to reach Go/NoGo decision, and then (2)how to select a suitable processing steps.

The conceptual scenario :

- I would like to predict the CPU load of a laptop (in %), as function of network I/O (samples taken every 5s, in Mbps in and out, for all interfaces wifi/eth, etc).
- Assume I have history data collected for both (CPU load%) and (networkIO mbps), for both training and test.
- Assume the laptop is getting used during the day(whatever task) but it's left on/idle during the night just to collect continuous data
- So finally, if I inject/or generate a certain amount of traffic (like downloading a movie), would like to predict the corresponding CPU load

The context that generating my question:

- Obviously there are a ton of other variables influencing the CPU load, like the disk I/O, encryption, the user tasks the laptop is performing, as well the OS background/virus, etc.
- As the tasks are not identified and they might occur randomly I would expect the relation between networkIO feature and the cpu-load% to be quasi random/no correlation

So - Intuitively I would expect the problem to be insolvable (one can't predict CPU load% only as function of the network IO).

But the more specific Q is - which data exploration techniques should be applied in order to "prove" that CPU load% can't be predicted only as function of the network IO ?

Searched SE, I haven't found a complete answer while I admit for not having RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

After researching with more specific terms it appears the topic has been discussed and has to do with "forecastability" of a time series. As far as I can understand a test 'for randomness' is critical, to establish if the input feature (in this case, network I/O) is basically 'noise' in respect with the output (cpu load%).